# Payment without order in Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment

We want to be able to take payment without creating an order. The record should be maintained in orders > transactions or any other panel. Very much like a donation.

Answer (score 0):

**To make a payment, you need to make a transaction.** It can be for any type of product, viz virtual, downloadable etc.

So, in my opinion, if you want to take payment like donation etc., you can **create a virtual product** (with Visibility: **Not visible individually**).

Then **create a custom form** in the frontend for taking payment. On the form submit, **send a request to a custom controller**, where you can place the order programmatically.

Also, you would need to **rewrite the email template for your custom order** to make it different from the default Magento's orders.

Additionally, you can **create a custom table to keep a record** of such payments, so that you can generate custom reports.

Please let me know if you have any other question.